# How to force vanilla keyboard color in flutter or android?

Tags: android, flutter

On my users specific hardware the keyboard have a weird blue default color, I don't know where it comes from, but it is totaly out of tune with my app

[image]

Is it possible for my app to reset or force display a classic colored keyboard ?

Comment: Ask Zebra. How a soft keyboard behaves is up to the developers of the soft keyboard, not you or I.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way.  Keyboards are an app.  There isn't just one Android keyboard-  every OEM can include a different one, or the user can install their own.  There is no default that they all have.  And there is no API to even hint to them a color, let alone force it to them.